# How to retain the child custom class of a base custom class <List> C# XNA

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna, polymorphism, collision-detection

This is my first time posting but i have found a lot on this site that has really helped my programming a lot.

I am attempting to write a simple game function to help better learn the ins and outs of programming in general and i have hit a wall.  When trying to make a function that takes my player and enemy class and easily draw, update, and check for collision i made a  of their parent class.  I then made a list of each child class ( player and enemy so i can add multiple of each at will) to add to the parent list.  I was hoping i could use the parent list to make the children classes do their corresponding functions with just one list call but whenever i run my code weird things happen.  For example if currentPlayers exceeds 1 then no enemy will be drawn, and vise verse with enemy.  I also cant run my collision function (properly) because it runs off the children lists and not the parent list.

I guess my real question is how do i keep the children list separate from the parent list but still use the parent list to make all their function calls.
For example use actorList to call Player.Update and enemy.Update, but still use actorList to call my collision detection and determine if actorList[i] is a player or enemy.  Thank you again for your time.
`

```
class ActorManager
{
    static ActorManager instance;
    List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();
    List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
    int currentActors;
    int currentEnemies =1;
    int currentPlayers = 1;
    List<Actor> actorList = new List<Actor>();

    public static ActorManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ActorManager();
            return instance;
        }

    }

    public void Init()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPlayers; i++)
        {
            players.Add(new Player());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < currentEnemies; i++)
        {
            enemies.Add(new Enemy());
        }


        // updates how many actors are currently in game
        this.UpdateCurrentActors();

        for (int i = 0; i < currentPlayers; i++)
        {  
            actorList.AddRange(players);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < currentEnemies; i++)
        {
            actorList.AddRange(enemies);
        }


    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        this.UpdateCurrentActors();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentActors; i++)
        {
            actorList[i].LoadContent(Content);
        }

    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < currentActors; i++)
        {
            actorList[i].Update(gameTime);
        }
        CheckPlayerHit();

        this.UpdateCurrentActors();

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentActors; i++)
        {
            actorList[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }

    void UpdateCurrentActors()
    {
        currentActors = (currentEnemies + currentPlayers);
    }

    void CheckPlayerHit()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPlayers; i++)
        {
            Rectangle thePlayer = new Rectangle((int)players[i].AttackBox.X, (int)players[i].AttackBox.Y, players[i].AttackBox.Width, players[i].AttackBox.Height);

            for (int j = 0; j < currentEnemies; j++)
            {
                Rectangle theEnemy = new Rectangle((int)enemies[j].HitBox.X, (int)enemies[j].HitBox.Y, enemies[j].HitBox.Width, enemies[j].HitBox.Height);

                if (thePlayer.Intersects(theEnemy))
                {
                    if (players[i].IsAttacking == true)
                    {
                        enemies[j].CurrentHealth -= players[i].Strength;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

}`

If there is anything i am forgetting please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, I'm by no means an expert in game programming, but I'll try and give you some helpful advice.

I'd recommend reading about Inheritance in general (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx is a link to some MSDN documentation with a C# focus).

In your case, if your classes derive from a common object `Actor`, you can store your children in a list of `Actors` and call any methods you have overridden as required.

e.g. As a simple example Running this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Actor> MyActors = new List<Actor>();

        MyActors.Add(new Player());        
        MyActors.Add(new Enemy());        
        MyActors.Add(new Player());

        foreach (var Actor in MyActors)
        {
            Actor.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Actor
{
    public string Name;

    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Actor does something");
    }

}

public class Player : Actor
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Player does something");
    }        
}

public class Enemy : Actor
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enemy does something");
    }       
}
```

Will produce this output:

```
Player does something
Enemy does something
Player does something
```

So by analogue, your child class specific `Update` methods will be called.

As far as your program goes, I can spot a few oddities that might help.

your `currentEnemies` and `currentPlayers` don't ever seem to be assigned to after initialisation, so your `currentActors` will always be 2. You would probably be better off using `enemies.Count` and `players.Count` to obtain your `currentEnemies` and `currentPlayers`, so they aren't out of sync.

You could probably remove your `UpdateCurrentActors` method as well, unless it's going to do something more complex. You should be able to get the number of current actors from your `actorList`, and it's another place you may end up out of sync.

Depending on what you'll eventually be doing with your players/enemies, you might actually be better off keeping them as separate lists anyway, especially if you're going to end up splitting them out a lot.

If I've suggested anything daft, let me know.

Comment: Your suggestion on keeping the two separate would work however i plan on using the actorList <List> to sort the classes based on their current Y position before I call the draw method.  This will give my 2d game the illusion that the higher the actor the farther back they are by having closer actors draw on top of them.  Also your suggestion on the virtual override is somewhat already implemented, I have each child class use the override function.